# Display list of messages with button 'read' and read the detailed message on click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an application wherein the admin can send messages to all its users.This part is coded and works fine. Now i want the user to read his messages such that he could see the message that has come and read it on click of button .Once the message is opened it must remain opened and the newly sent messages should be hidden which could be read on button click again.

Now how this can be implemented? list view or grid view will do provided all the criteria's are handled well.

I have a table which contains the messages and the ids of the user to which it is send. So no problem of query to get the message only thing is to display it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `gridview` and `DetailView` to show message and button. once button is clicked, expand that row and collapse other rows.  You need to write code in `OnRowDataBound` to show/hide detail view.

Your detail view will contains actual message, while the main grid will contain master information of your message.

You can look [here](http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/gridview-inside-detailsview-with-expand-collapse-in-Asp-Net-1085.aspx) to see somewhat similar implementation.